# Is it possible to modify find's matching criteria according to the $cond

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, find, mongodb-query

I have a `flag` and a `key`.

If the `flag` is `true` I want to list the documents whose `name` field includes the `key`.

Otherwise- if the `flag` is `false`- I want to search the key on `name` or `surname` fields.

Here the example of collection;

```
{id: 1, name: "green" , surname: "brown"},
{id: 2, name: "black" , surname: "brown"},
{id: 3, name: "brown" , surname: "yellow"}
```

if flag: true, key: brown, I expect;

```
{id: 1, name: "green" , surname: "brown"},
{id: 2, name: "black" , surname: "brown"},
{id: 3, name: "brown" , surname: "yellow"}
```

if flag: false, key: brown, I expect;

```
{id: 3, name: "brown" , surname: "yellow"}
```

How can I do this find using $cond?

I can do it as;

```
if(flag){ 
  db.collection.find({name: key})
}else{
  db.collection.find({$or: [{name: key}, {surname: key}])
}
```

Is something like that possible? But this throws an error. How can I edit?

```
db.collection.find({$cond: [ if: { flag }, then: {$or: [{name: "brown"}, {surname: "brown"}]}, else: {name: "brown"} ]})
```

Comment: `$cond` is conditonal aggregation operator. It will not work with regular queries. May be its better to keep that logic on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

$cond is an aggregation pipeline operator and you won't be able to use as you were expecting. It would be easy to do it on client side as you have mentioned.

If you *MUST* do it in query itself; will have to manipulate conditions such that

a) in one query, a true value for flag results condition to be true and false results condition to be false.

b) in second query, a true value for flag results condition to be false and false results condition to be true.

And then [or] above conditions.

You could use $exists of an attribute that ***always exists*** in document to give true for a flag = true; and use $exists  of an attribute that will ***never exist*** in document to give false for a flag = true.

Here is a solution using above logic:

```
var flag = true;
var key = "brown";
db.collection.find({
    $or : [ {
        $and : [ { _id : { $exists : flag } }, 
                 { name : key } ]
    }, {
        $and : [ { _id_nonExist : { $exists : flag } }, 
                 { $or : [ { name : key }, { surname : key } ] } ]
    } ]
})
```

I have gone by your description "*If the flag is true I want to list the documents whose name field includes the key.
Otherwise- if the flag is false- I want to search the key on name or surname fields.*"